# jdbc MySQLTransientConnectionException exception with a particular query in production

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring

I have a Spring+hibernate+mysql+jstl architecture, running in a linux CENTOS production enviroment.

I added a quartz (schedualer) module, my friend quartz checks every 10 seconds a folder for new files, and if he finds it, vadilates and loads the files in database and moves the file. The programs works find in my MacBook, however in production im getting a jdbc error when trying to load the data into the database, but everything else database related works fine.

I load the file in database with a JAVA like:

```
String queryString = "LOAD DATA INFILE  '"+path+"' INTO TABLE  `branch_to_product` FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ';' ENCLOSED BY  '\"' ESCAPED BY  '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\\n'(\n" +
            "`product_model` ,  `branch_to_product_monthly_rotation` ,  `branch_to_product_quantity`\n" +
            ")";

    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
```

If i run the sql from phpmyadmin's it runs find also.

These are the error i see in the logs:

```
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.NotImplemented from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransientConnectionException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLDataException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.DeadlockTimeoutRollbackMarker from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded java.sql.SQLRecoverableException from /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]  
[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.PoolUtils from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/naming-factory-dbcp.jar]  
[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.KeyedObjectPool from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/naming-factory-dbcp.jar]  
[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.PoolUtils$KeyedObjectPoolMinIdleTimerTask from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/naming-factory-dbcp.jar]  
[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.PoolUtils$ObjectPoolMinIdleTimerTask from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/naming-factory-dbcp.jar]  
[Loaded sun.net.ConnectionResetException from /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/rt.jar]  
[Loaded org.hibernate.action.BulkOperationCleanupAction from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/shared/lib/hibernate.jar]  
0
[Loaded org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/shared/lib/hibernate.jar]  
09:19:25,633 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - Access denied for user 'jardinde_fp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)  
09:19:25,633 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - Access denied for user 'jardinde_fp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple authentication error:

> ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - Access denied for user 'jardinde_fp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Make sure that the credentials for the application are allowed by the server.

These lines in the logs you posted just show the JVM loading these class files from their JARs, they are not an error or the real problem (the JVM loads classes the first time it finds/executes codes that references them, and it has to walk the full graph of references):

> [Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]
>   [Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.NotImplemented from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]
>   [Loaded com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransientConnectionException from file:/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.33/common/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar]

Comment: I understand your logic makes much sense, however, with credentials you mean that database login and password right ? but they work fine with other parts of the program, and i checked them and they are OK, or are there other elements that make the credentials that i should check ?

Comment: IIRC mysql differentiates between allowing `jardinde_fp` to login from certain IPs and allowing the same user to login from 'localhost' - make sure both are added. Double-check the password is correct, etc. Recommend consulting the MySQL documentation for more.

Answer (score -1):

Added the word LOCAL to the query and worked !

```
String queryString = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '"+path+"' INTO TABLE  `branch_to_product` FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ';' ENCLOSED BY  '\"' ESCAPED BY  '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\\n'(\n" +
            "`product_model` ,  `branch_to_product_monthly_rotation` ,  `branch_to_product_quantity`\n" +
            ")";

    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
```